# UnicodeDecodeError on text comparison

Tags: python

While performing a substring match, I get `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 8: ordinal not in range(128)`

Code:

```
for bhk in bed_bath:
            if "Bedroom" in bhk.text or "Chambre à coucher" in bhk.text or "Slaapkamer" in bhk.text:
                bhk_count += 1
```

How do I resolve it?

I have included below lines on the beginning of my file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7

Comment: Well, Guilermo Zapata’s answer explains everything :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using python 2.

The problem is happening because `bhk.text` is a unicode string.

When you do a comparison like `"Chambre à coucher" in bhk.text` the literal string, which is an non-unicode strings needs to be converted to a unicode string.

Since you declared your file to have a utf-8 encoding, the unicode char `à` is encoded as string `"\xc3\xa0"`.

When python tries to convert char "0xc3" using the default codec (`ascii`), it cannot map it to a unicode char and throws that error.

The solution would be to declare the strings with non-ascii characters as unicode, like:

```
u"Chambre à coucher" in bhk.text
```

Comment: I have a same problem with property_price = property_price.split('€')[1] . How do i solve ?

Comment: Same problem, `€` is not an ascii character, so use a unicode string instead, .e.g `property_price.split(u'€')[1]`.  Please note that appending a string literal with an `u` will make it a unicode string, otherwise it's only a plain string.

Comment: Okay got it . Thank you